# Is it possible to set up SSH to Google Cloud Platform VM just with user and password (no private/public keys)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have to set up ssh connection to VM on Google Cloud Platform that won't requiere any keys, just username and password. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The first rule of SSH security is to disable password based SSH logins. If you decide to enable password login, create a firewall rule to only allow your IP address to connect on port 22 (SSH). https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-root-login-via-ssh/

Answer (score 5):

To enable SSH password authentication on Compute Engine instances, you must edit the sshd_config file, to do that first go to your instance by clicking on the “SSH” button next to the instance name on Cloud Console.

Then a terminal appears and you should be able to edit the config file using: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Then, change the line: `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Also, if you need to have directly root ssh access with username/password authentication, also change the line: `PermitRootLogin no` to `PermitRootLogin yes`

After making that changes, restart the SSH service by running the following command:

1.- If your OS is Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo service ssh restart`

2.- If your OS is CentOS/RedHat: `sudo service sshd restart`

Now you should be able to login with username/password authentication.